# How to stop users from spamming the submit button and sending multiple ajax requests?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a from with an input which is disabled unless the textbox has text inside, but when a user adds text and smashes the submit button as fast as they can the ajax runs multiple times inserting the same text in the database over and over, this is my submit the form jQuery;

```
$('#content').on("submit", "#message_reply", function(){

    $.ajax({
        type: $(this).attr('method'),
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        headers: {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'},
        dataType: 'json',
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function(data){
            if(!data.success){
                $.notify(data.error, "error");
            }else{
                $('#newMessage').prop('disabled', true);
                $('#newMessage').val('');
                $("#content").load("<?php echo Config::get('URL'); ?>messages/message/" + jQuery('input[name="message"]').val(), function(){
                    $('#content').fadeIn('slow');
                });
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Code to check if textbox has text inside:

```
$(function(){
    $('#newMessage').on("keyup", function(){
        if($(this).val()){
            $('#reply_submit').prop('disabled', false);
        }else{
            $('#reply_submit').prop('disabled', true);
        }
    });
});
```

and my form:

```
            <form action="<?php echo config::get('URL'); ?>messages/reply" method="POST" id="message_reply">
                <input type="hidden" name="message" value="<?php echo System::escape($this->message->message_id); ?>">
                <textarea id="newMessage" class="form-control" name="reply" rows="4" placeholder=""></textarea>
                <input style="margin-top: 20px;" type="submit" id="reply_submit" disabled name="submit" value="<?php echo System::translate("Send"); ?>" class="btn btn-success pull-right">
            </form>
            <!-- wysiwyg !-->
```

As you can see I am trying to disable the text box and empty the value, but that doesn't work in the space of a few milliseconds allowing the same data to be submitted 3 or 4 times

How can I stop this from happening?

Comment: Disable the button at the top of your handler code, re-enable in success:? - this is synchronous so will prevent what you observe.

Comment: @AlexK. I answered the same thing. LoL. `:D`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just `disable` the button once you click, and enable it back after a timeOut, after the AJAX is successful:

```
$('#content').on("submit", "#message_reply", function(){
  $this = $("#reply_submit");
  $this.prop("disabled", true);
  $.ajax({
    type: $(this).attr('method'),
    url: $(this).attr('action'),
    headers: {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'},
    dataType: 'json',
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    success: function(data){
      if(!data.success){
        $.notify(data.error, "error");
      }else{
        $('#newMessage').prop('disabled', true);
        $('#newMessage').val('');
        $("#content").load("<?php echo Config::get('URL'); ?>messages/message/" + jQuery('input[name="message"]').val(), function(){
          $('#content').fadeIn('slow');
        });
      }
    },
    complete: function () {
      setTimeout(function () {
        $this.prop("disabled", false);
      }, 1000);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: `this` is the `form`, not submit button

Comment: @A.Wolff Thanks. Corrected. Check?

Comment: I see one other issue, if request fails, the submit button would still be disabled :)

Comment: @A.Wolff We can move this to the `always`.

Comment: Ya, that's what i was thinking while posting it as answer :)

Comment: @A.Wolff UPdated `:D`

Comment: Oops but `always()` is deferred method, not ajax callback option, you need to use `complete` instead if you wish to use the ajax option. I edited this part and removed redundancy

Comment: @A.Wolff Thank you for your edits buddy... It was awesome. `:)`

Answer (score 1):

Just disable relevant `:submit` element of `form` and renable it on ajax complete callback, e.g:

```
$('#content').on("submit", "#message_reply", function() {
  var $submit = $(this).find(':submit').prop('disabled', true);
  $.ajax(...).always(function() {
    $submit.prop('disabled', false);
  });
  return false;
});
```